# I am facing error when run a project at google apps engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

> Fatal error: The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum
>   execution time and   Fatal error: The request was aborted because it
>   exceeded the maximum execution time. in
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/log/LogService.php
>   on line 413
>   The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum execution time. in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/log/LogService.php on line 413

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

When I going to run my project at google apps engine , it was display an error i.e

> Fatal error: The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum
>   execution time and Fatal error: The request was aborted because it
>   exceeded the maximum execution time. in
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/log/LogService.php
>   on line 413 The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum
>   execution time. in
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/log/LogService.php
>   on line 413

I solved this problem just add three line at app.yaml file
Those line are

```
instance_class: B8
manual_scaling:
  instances: 5
```

Please check below link once
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/